# Impersonated permissions from granting execute of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

/Now if created a login as below:/

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE LOGIN [userx] WITH PASSWORD=N'P@ssw0rd', DEFAULTDATABASE=[master], DEFAULTLANGUAGE=[usenglish], CHECKEXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

ALTER LOGIN [userx] Enable
GO

/then created a user inside a database with only the public role:/

USE [test]
GO
CREATE USER [userx] FOR LOGIN [userx]
GO

/ then created a database role with the below securables:/

CREATE ROLE [db_executer]
GO

use [test]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE TO [dbexecuter]
GO
use [test]
GO
DENY DELETE TO [dbexecuter]
GO
use [test]
GO
DENY INSERT TO [dbexecuter]
GO
use [test]
GO
DENY UPDATE TO [dbexecuter]
GO

/then assigned the user to that created role:/

USE [test]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_executer] ADD MEMBER [userx]
GO

/ and created the below simple table and SPs:/

USE [test]
GO
create table t1
(
id int

)

go

create proc t1read
as
begin
select * from t1
end

go

create proc t1write
as
begin
insert into t1
select 2
end

GO

create proc t1delete
as
begin
delete t1

end

go

create proc t1update
as
begin
update t1 set id=10

end
```

/ Now, when opening a new connection with userx, I can execute all SPs and reading and writing and deleting data from the underlying table with having only execute granted on the database and deny write/delete/insert on the whole database./

the screenshot for the privileges to the userx and the public role also attached

/ Now I will take this furhter, If i explicitly denied delete/update/insert on the table itself:/

```
use [test]
GO
DENY DELETE ON [dbo].[t1] TO [dbexecuter]
GO
use [test]
GO
DENY INSERT ON [dbo].[t1] TO [dbexecuter]
GO
use [test]
GO
DENY UPDATE ON [dbo].[t1] TO [db_executer]
GO
```

-- still I can execute (userx) all SPs for update/delete/insert

NOTE: I am on SQL Server 2014 CU-GDR

Comment: Ayman, you should include the info here in the question, otherwise if the link goes stale there isn't anything useful left here.

Comment: I recommend becoming familiar with the formatting options available to you in the editor so that you can present you questions in an easy to read way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  That's not a bug.

That's Ownership Chaining.  Documented here: [Procedural Code and Ownership Chaining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authorization-and-permissions-in-sql-server#procedural-code-and-ownership-chaining).

And it's always been a fundamental (and useful) security behavior of SQL Server.  If you want to disable it, just put the stored procedures in a schema owned by a different user than the tables.

The idea (which other RDBMSs share, but implement differently) is that it's more secure if I don't have to give direct CRUD access to tables to the users, and it's redundant to give them EXECUTE on your procedure, and then have to also grant them permissions on your tables.

Comment: but that is talking about select which I don't have issues with. the DUI statements also getting the permissions on the underlying table even if I deny them.

I don't see any sense in that especially by mentioning that "Denying permission at any level, overrides a related grant." in the document of Microsoft SQL Server 2017 and Azure SQL Database permissions infographic.pdf.

Comment: for example, if I have a database with thousands of SPs and grant the execute permission on the database. by that, I granted data modification to the whole database.

and should I go through all SPs to grant execute permissions on only SPs doing SELECT? when I want to grant a user read/execute permission

and if that SP changed in the future to do updates, he will implicitly have the write permission without any notification to me.

Comment: It is clearly documented that Ownership Chaining prevents _all_ permissions checking. "If both objects have the same owner, permissions on the referenced object are not checked"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Although it still doesn't make sense for me.